# Getting null value when accessing fields from result in Searcher in Vespa

Tags: vespa

My Searcher is given below. When I hit search API then in my Searcher, I am getting null values when I tried to get fields of document. I am able to get id, relavance and source but not fields. Why is it so?Am I doing something wrong? Please help.

```
@Override
public Result search(Query query, Execution execution) {
    // pass it down the chain to get a result
    Result result = execution.search(query);

    String title = result.hits().get(0).getField("title");

    System.out.println(title);

    // return the result up the chain
    return result;
}
```

I am getting *null* value in title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use execution.fill(result) to fill the result before accessing fields. See also https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/reference/inspecting-structured-data.html

Answer (score 2):

This is because results are initially surfaced without field data added (for performance).

Add

```
execution.fill(result);
```

before accessing fields (send the summary class to fill as second argument if you have multiple ones).